# Converting an absolute pathname to something more personal

Tags: .net

I have a pathname `C:\Users\<user name>\Documents\Folder` returned from using the FileBrowserDialog, that I would prefer to display using the `My Documents\Folder`.

Other than using

```
pathname.StartsWith(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments)
```

to see if the pathname 'belongs' in My Documents, is there another way of converting the pathname to use `My Documents`?

Comment: Why display as `My Documents\Folder` rather than `Documents\Folder` ?

Comment: Because it's a shorthand and should work across all versions of Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this approach which loops the parent directories up to the root:

```
DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo("C:\\Users\\Tim\\Documents\\Folder\\file.ext");
string myDocs = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
bool isMyDocs = directory.FullName == myDocs;
while (!isMyDocs && (directory = directory.Parent) != null)
    isMyDocs = directory.FullName == myDocs;
// use your personal folder-name acc. to isMyDocs
```

**Update**:

> I should re-phrase the question. I want to end up with shorthand path
>   notation e.g. \My Documents\Folder\file.ext

I thought it would be clear:

```
string yourFile = "C:\\Users\\Tim\\Documents\\Folder\\file.ext";
string yourDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(yourFile);
DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(yourDir);
string myDocs = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
bool isMyDocs = directory.FullName == myDocs;
while (!isMyDocs && (directory = directory.Parent) != null)
    isMyDocs = directory.FullName == myDocs;
string personalPath = yourDir;
if(isMyDocs)
{
    personalPath = Path.Combine("My Documents", "Folder", Path.GetFileName(yourFile));
}
```

Comment: or `Path.GetDirectoryName` instead of `DirectoryInfo` class.

Comment: @nawfal: but i need `DirectoryInfo.Parent` to loop up to the root.

Comment: I should re-phrase the question. I want to end up with shorthand path notation e.g. \My Documents\Folder\file.ext

Comment: Thanks for that. With one or two minor corrections, your code works. Looks like I'm wasting my time anyway because trying something like File.Exists("\My Documents\Folder\File.ext") fails when the file does actually exist.

Comment: @EmJay: Why should `File.Exists` return `true` for a path that was created by you? I thought that would be just a modification for the user. Don't modify the original path.

Comment: I suppose the question should have been "Can I use 'My Documents' (or 'Documents') as the root of longer pathname. e.g. \Documents\Folder\filename.ext instead of C:\Users\<name>\My Documents\Folder\filename.ext"? (this on Win/7)